# Query : sum for all key containing given substring

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following table:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Luka, Jean | 1 |
| Luka | 2 |
| Jean | 3 |
| Luka, Jean, Etienne | 4 |
| Luka, Jean | 5 |

I would like to have the sum total of every lane containing the name "Luka" and the name "Jean". I am able to have this result but for each unique key containing these names.

My query is : `=QUERY(A1:B,"select A, sum(B) where A contains 'Luka' and A contains 'Jean' group by A")`

The result is:

|  | sum |
| --- | --- |
| Luka, Jean | 1 |
| Luka, Jean, Etienne | 4 |

However I would like to have the total result for this query in one unique cell. I think I need to have nested queries but I don't know how to do it.

Expected result :

`5` (in one cell without any header or key)

Comment: Try this `=Sum(QUERY(A:B,"select B where A contains 'Luka' and A contains 'Jean' "))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(A1:B,"select A, sum(B) where A contains 'Luka' and A contains 'Jean' group by A"), "select sum(Col2)", 1), 2)`

or an actually easier way using your formula itself `=INDEX(QUERY(A1:B,"select sum(B) where A contains 'Luka' and A contains 'Jean'"), 2)`

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems to me that the total given the sample data in your post should be 10, not 5 (it seems you were not including row 5 for some reason).

Assuming I am correct:

`=SUM(FILTER(B:B,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Luka",A:A)*SEARCH("Jean",A:A))))`